# Dua or Quranic verse

Tags: quran, dua

Need Quranic verse and Dua to face the fears,overcome procrastination & stop making mind excuses & start doing the things to achieve the Deen & Dunya goals.

Comment: there is a book called HISNUL MUSLIM by Sa'id bin Ali bin Wahf Al-Qahtani, it has a vast collection of authentic duas from quran and sunnah. it is readily available and free. you can find it as an mobile application too.

Comment: @Ahmed Nazeem Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Anas ibn Maalik (رضي الله عنه) reported: The Prophet (ﷺ) used to say:

اللَّهُمَّ إِنِّي أَعُوذُ بِكَ مِنَ الْهَمِّ وَالْحَزَنِ، وَالْعَجْزِ وَالْكَسَلِ، وَالْبُخْلِ وَالْجُبْنِ، وَضَلَعِ الدَّيْنِ، وَغَلَبَةِ الرِّجَالِ

Allaahumma ‘innee ‘a’oothu bika minal-hammi walhazani, wal’ajzi walkasali, walbukhli waljubni, wa dhala’id-dayni wa ghalabatir-rijaal

(O Allah, I seek refuge in You from grief and sadness, from weakness and from laziness, from miserliness and from being cowardly, from being overcome by debt and overpowered by people)

[source](https://preciousgemsfromthequranandsunnah.wordpress.com/2018/11/25/dua-for-anxiety-sorrow-laziness-miserliness-cowardice-debt-protection-from-enemies/)